# Magento 1.9 Home page ok but categories are very slow ( no products)

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category, home-page

What maybe an issue of slow **categories** and **sub categories** without any **products** at all? 
My **home page** is not too fast but at least I understand what can be done 
(banners compression, less requests and such thinks can help).

But the problem is about categories. They simply very slow and they are empty. It does not have even **1 product** inside. So when I locate in **category A** and want to go **Category B** or any category or subcategory it simply takes about 12 seconds and longer.

Thanks

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com or here. RAM size of your MySQL Host server A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini Text results of: B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; after minimum 24 hours UPTIME C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;  D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;;  AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, ulimit -a for a linux/unix list of limits, iostat -xm 5 3 when system is busy for an idea of IOPS by device, df -h for a linux/unix free space list by device, for server tuning analysis.

Comment: Are you running MySQL 5.7 by any chance?